# D3 Javascript bar chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to write a tutorial about d3 and I found couple websites that can help but with not enough details.

I have the following code that outputs a bar chart:

```
<html>
<head>
<div id="mainGraph">
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var t = 1, // start time (seconds since epoch)
    v = 0, // start value (subscribers)
    data = d3.range(33).map(next); // starting dataset

 function next() {
   return {
    time: ++t,
     value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(80, v + 3 *( Math.random() - .5))
   };
}
setInterval(function() {
   data.shift();
   data.push(next());
 }, 1500);

  var w = 40,
      h = 100;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, w]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
     .rangeRound([0, h]);

     var chart = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg:svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", w * data.length + 10)
     .attr("height", h);

     chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) + 5; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) + 5; })
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

     chart.append("svg:line")
     .attr("x1", 0)
     .attr("x2", w * data.length)
     .attr("y1", h + 5)
     .attr("y2", h + 5)
     .attr("stroke", "#000");





    </script>           
    </body>
    </html>
```

the problem that I am facing now is when I try to change the set of data so i am trying to put v in function of t like v = Math.exp (t)
this is not working and its giving me a black line only even though I changed the interval of max and min.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
   data.shift();
   data.push(next());
 }, 1500);
```

`setInterval` makes the code run every 1.5 seconds

```
   data.shift();
```

Removes the first element of array `data` (which is filled with random numbers)

```
   data.push(next());
```

Inserts a new random value at the end of the array. `next()` is a function that generates random numbers.

So, in summary, `data.push(next());` inserts a new random value at the end of array `data`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, I still have another problem I am trying to add a function to the v variable per example I want to put v as v = Math.exp (t)
the thing is that it is not working even though I changed the interval of maximum and minimum but it outputs only a line.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you consider passing in fixed data for your tutorial, rather than using a number generator.  It's more common that chart users generate the data, separately, and then pass the data to the charting tool.  I always find it useful to do so.

A common data input format is to use the D3.csv post-parsed string format...

```
var dataSet1 = [
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 1", magnitude: 54, link: "http://www.if4it.com"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 2", magnitude: 21, link: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 3", magnitude: 31, link: "http://www.if4it.com/resources.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 4", magnitude: 14, link: "http://www.if4it.com/taxonomy.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 5", magnitude: 19, link: "http://www.if4it.com/disciplines.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 6", magnitude: 47, link: "http://www.if4it.com"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 7", magnitude: 27, link: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"}];
```

I have a working example on github called "[Multiple Vertical Bar Charts Mixed In With Common HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2164562)."

One thing I'd like to try to get to work is using events to control things like highlighting specific bars in the chart as I mouseover the text legends to the right of the graph.  If you know how to do so, please feel free to elaborate.

I hope this helps.

Frank